# Null Pointer Exception in Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am new to android programming. I've tried to make reminder application. But when I added alarm manager to my codes. It gave me `NullPointerException`. I have checked the question asked before. But they didn't help me. I also checked if there was the thing that I didn't initialize. But I didn't find. Also I checked my `xml`. I thought that maybe there was a problem in button(`android:onClick`). But also there was no problem in there. I know there are lots of question about this subject. But can you help me ?

This is my ImageActivity class

```
 public void addImage(View v)
   {

    int year = datepicker.getYear();
    int month = datepicker.getMonth();
    int day = datepicker.getDayOfMonth();
    int hour = timepicker.getCurrentHour();
    int minute = timepicker.getCurrentMinute();

    Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();

    String uniqueid = System.currentTimeMillis()+"";
    c.set(year,month,day,hour,minute);
    long firstTime = c.getTimeInMillis();


    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent  intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, mAlarmSender);

    db3.insertRecordimage(fileName2, String.valueOf(year), String.valueOf(month), String.valueOf(day), String.valueOf(hour), String.valueOf(minute));



}
```

This is my XML

```
<Button

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:onClick="addImage"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
```

And this is my logcat

```
06-05 22:29:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(31354):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)06-05 22:29:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(31354):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 22:29:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(31354):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 22:29:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(31354):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
06-05 22:29:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(31354):    ... 11 more
06-05 22:29:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(31354): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 22:29:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(31354):    at com.example.pc.remindme.ImageActivity.addImage(ImageActivity.java:132)
06-05 22:29:49.916: E/AndroidRuntime(31354):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: What is line 132 of ImageActivity?

Comment: It is "AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);"

Comment: I think that null is your context. Try this AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent  intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

Comment: in this line only one object reference is used. It is "context". Check what is it and where it is assigned.

Comment: @Vigen I tried what u have said. But still gave me same error.

Comment: Can you show your ImageActivity.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the NullPointerException is a result of this line like you stated in your comment:

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

then I guess the context is null at this point. If your method is in an activity you already got your context like that:

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

If you're in an inner class or similiar you can use:

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager) ImageActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I have used but they didn't work. I have still same error.

Comment: There shouldn't be any NullPointerException at that line anymore, you also have to replace any other recurrence of 'context' with 'this'. Maybe there is another NullPointerException anywhere else then.